# comparing strings in consecutive lines with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with lines,

```
apple
apple
mango
mango
mango
cherry
cherry
cherry
cherry
```

I want to get the line numbers where a string in the current line is different from that in the next line, e.g.:

```
2 apple
5 mango 
9 cherry
```

I am using this command, which is not working for me:

```
awk '{if ($1!=next);{ print}; next=$1}' file > file.ends
```

What is the mistake here?

Comment: thank you all for the replies it helped me a lot ...awk is awsome..and you people too..

Answer (score 1):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk '$0!=f && NR>1 {print (NR-1),f} {f=$0} END {print NR,$0}' file
2 apple
5 mango
9 cherry
```

Test is line is different from previous, then print previous line number `NR-1` and previous data `f`
`END` is used to get the last.  `NR>1` is used to prevent first line to get a hit.

Answer (score 1):

@Jotne's answer provides an elegant solution to your problem.

As for why your approach didn't work:

- `next` is a reserved word that means "skip remaining patterns on the input line", i.e.: proceed to the next input line, ignoring subsequent pattern-action pairs in the `awk` program.
- Aside from being an illegal variable name, `next` is a misnomer: it contains the *previous* line, so a better name would be `prev`, for instance.
- Your `if` statement is mistakenly terminated with `;`, resulting in the subsequent block, `{ print}` ALWAYS getting executed.
- You're missing output of the row index and you're printing the *current* line (by simply saying `print`), even though you should be printing the *previous* one.
- You're not dealing with the *last* input line, whose - non-existent - next line is by definition always different from the last line.

A fixed version of your command would look as follows (hmm... as I look at this, I realize that this is awfully close to @Jotne's solution - to his credit; I hope that my comments provide some added value):

```
awk '
    # Starting with the 2nd line, compare the current line with the previous one
    # and, if it differs, print the *previous* line along with its line index.
  NR>1 && $0 != prev { print NR-1, prev }
    # Save the current line for the next iteration.
  {prev=$0} 
    # Output the final line, whose following - non-existent - line is by
    # by definition always different.
  END { print NR, $0 }
  ' file
```