# AWK match string using regex and combine with previous string

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have been reviewing articles and posts on how to match and compare strings but I am struggling to put the two together, unfortunately, I do not have an example awk command that I am trying to make work because I can't seem to even get that far. Below is what I have been trying to work with, I found it at [comparing strings in consecutive lines with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998185/comparing-strings-in-consecutive-lines-with-awk) my hope was that if I changed the match condition from the previous line to instead be anything under 32 id start to get some output I could try to work with, and i modified the NR to start on the 4th string which would be the first subnet mask.

```
awk '$0<=32 && NR>3 {print (NR)/f} {f=$0} END {print NR,$0}'
```

My current input looks like this:

```
hostname1           hostname2           127.0.0.1             27              127.0.0.2              24              127.0.0.3             28              hostname3           127.0.0.4               27              127.0.0.5              24              127.0.0.6            28              127.0.0.7             27              127.0.0.8              24       127.0.0.9             28
```

The output I am looking to have would be:

```
hostname1           hostname2           127.0.0.1/27              127.0.0.2/24              127.0.0.3/28              hostname3           127.0.0.4/27              127.0.0.5/24              127.0.0.6/28              127.0.0.7/27              127.0.0.8/24       127.0.0.9/28
```

These are IP addresses and subnet masks, my thinking was to look for 16-32 using a regex, match for the previous string which would always be an IP address, and combine the two. Does anyone have any examples of this being done? I have to use variables as the number of inputted IP addresses and subnet combinations vary

Comment: You don't show your current _input_

Comment: fix output to input, my b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's#\(\<[[:digit:].]\+\)[^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]\+\)#\1/\2#g' input_file
hostname1           hostname2           127.0.0.1/27              127.0.0.2/24              127.0.0.3/28              hostname3           127.0.0.4/27              127.0.0.5/24              127.0.0.6/28              127.0.0.7/27              127.0.0.8/24       127.0.0.9/28
```

`\(\<[[:digit:].]\+\)` - This is the first capture group as it is enclosed within capturing parenthesis. This capture group will retain digits and periods. There is a word boundary `\<` at the start of the integer match.

`[^[:digit:]]*` - Exclude this match as it is not within parenthesis, This will exclude everything up till the next occurance of an integer character.

`\([[:digit:]]\+\)` - Second capture group which will retain one or more integer characters.

`\1/\2` - This is the replacement, as we captured two groups, they can be returned with back refernce `\1` and `\2` respectively.

The default delimiter `/` for `sed` has been changed to `#` to avoid conflicting with your
data which will also contain `/` after the replacement.

Comment: Can you explain this? I was just starting to google how to do it using sed

Comment: Why intermix `[:digit:]` and `[0-9]`? - just pick one. Also, you're using GNU-specific word boundaries so why not add `-E` and then you don't need any of those escapes in the script except the `\<`.

Comment: @user2954003 Please check edit

Comment: A host name can contain `-`. If you change `hostname2` to `hostname-2` you'll get undesirable output that includes `hostname-2/127.0.0.1/27`.

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed. Changed. Good point Ed, I just seem to default to BRE

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU or BSD sed for `-E` to enable EREs:

```
$ sed -E 's:(\.[0-9]+)\t\t([0-9]+):\1/\2:g' file
hostname1               hostname2               127.0.0.1/27            127.0.0.2/24            127.0.0.3/28           hostname3                127.0.0.4/27            127.0.0.5/24            127.0.0.6/28            127.0.0.7/27           127.0.0.8/24             127.0.0.9/28
```

Comment: my understanding is this works by matching the final number in the IP address followed by two tabs and the beginning of the subnet mask number, but i do not understand what :\1/\2: does

Comment: Correct. `:` is separating the parts of the sed command (the regexp and the replacement). `\1` refers to to the text that matched the regexp segment within the 1st `(...)` capture group and `\2` the 2nd one, same as in the currently accepted answer.

Comment: @EdMorton : Your regex using `gnu-sed`  :: `gsed -E 's:(\.[0-9]+)\t\t([0-9]+):\1/\2:g'
 ..943.233.3953.21.11  1114111    
 ..943.233.3953.21.11/1114111`

Answer (score 0):

With awk, it's a longer program. This one uses [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) specifically

```bash
gawk -i join '{
    n = 0
    delete result
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /^[0-9.]+$/ && $(i+1) ~ /^[0-9]+/)
            result[++n] = $i "/" $(++i)
        else
            result[++n] = $i
    print join(result, 1, n, "\t")
}' input.file
```

outputs

```
hostname1   hostname2   127.0.0.1/27    127.0.0.2/24    127.0.0.3/28    hostname3   127.0.0.4/27    127.0.0.5/24    127.0.0.6/28    127.0.0.7/27    127.0.0.8/24    127.0.0.9/28
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task for following way, let `file.txt` be TAB-separated file

```
hostname1           hostname2           127.0.0.1             27              127.0.0.2              24              127.0.0.3             28              hostname3           127.0.0.4               27              127.0.0.5              24              127.0.0.6            28              127.0.0.7             27              127.0.0.8              24       127.0.0.9             28
```

then

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=1){printf "%s%s",$i,$i~/^[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}$/?"/":"\t"};print $NF}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
hostname1   hostname2   127.0.0.1/27    127.0.0.2/24    127.0.0.3/28    hostname3   127.0.0.4/27    127.0.0.5/24    127.0.0.6/28    127.0.0.7/27    127.0.0.8/24    127.0.0.9/28
```

Explanation: I use `for` loop to iterate over all but last field of given live. For each field I use `printf` to output that field followed by `/` if it does look like decimal IP address (1...3 digits followed by dot followed by 1...3 digits followed by dot followed by 1...3 digits followed by dot followed by 1...3 digits) or `\t` (TAB) character otherwise. For implementing this choice I use so-called ternary operator *condition*`?`*valueiftrue*`:`*valueiffalse*. After that I just `print` last field (`$NF`) as it has always be followed by newline.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*